# Python and Seaborn how to plot two categorical features using barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

I am trying to solve kaggle's titanic competition.

I need to generate a plot where X is representing `Sex` having male and female as values. And Y as two variables 0 and 1.

From this, I need to see how many males/females survived.

I am trying the following:

```
sns.barplot(x='Sex', y='Survived', data=train)
```

But I am getting a plot representing percentage of each male and female:

[image]

Any idea how to create stacked bar using seaborn?

I need to plot 2 features, each of them having 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably try with "Grouped barplots". Interestingly, the seaborn's gallery page has a nice [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_barplot.html) about it... with titanic data as an example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Load the example Titanic dataset
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# Draw a nested barplot to show survival for class and sex
g = sns.catplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex", data=titanic,
                height=6, kind="bar", palette="muted")
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("survival probability")
```